# Plotting the solution of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to plot solution of differential equations. I can get real values out of my function, and get no errors from the `Plot`, but also no curve shows up.

Assume initial condition `θ[0] = π/6, θ'[0] = 1`.

Here is my code:

```
Clearall

T[t_] = 
  ExpToTrig[
    DSolve[
      {θ''[t] + 2 g θ[t]/(3(R - ρ)) == 0 /. {R -> 1, ρ -> 2, g -> 9.81}, 
       θ[0] == 0.52, θ'[0] == 1}, θ[t], t]]

T1[t_] = 
  NDSolve[
    {θ''[t] + 2 g θ[t]/(3*(R - ρ)  == 0 /. {R -> 1, ρ -> 2, g -> 9.81 },
     θ[0] == π/6, θ'[0] == 1}, θ[t], {t, 0, 10}]

 T[t]
 Plot[T[t], {t, 0.1, 1}]
 T[2]
 T1[2]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try these syntax fixes `T[t_] =ExpToTrig[θ[t]/.DSolve[{θ''[t] + 2*g*θ[t]/(3*(R - ρ)) ==0 /. {R->1, ρ->2, g->9.81 },θ[0]==0.52,θ'[0] == 1}, θ[t], t][[1]]];
T1[t_] = θ[t]/.NDSolve[{θ''[t] + 2*g*θ[t]/(3*(R - ρ))==0/.{R->1, ρ->2, g->9.81 }, θ[0] == \[Pi]/6, θ'[0] == 1}, θ[t], {t, 0, 10}][[1]];` and then you can use your last four lines `T[t], Plot[...`

Comment: Be aware that `Clearall` standing alone accomplishes nothing. It is not a command. It is a symbol naming a function. You must give it arguments. Hower, in your situation `Clear` is more appropriate. It not a command either, so give it arguments.

Comment: @m_goldberg `Clearall` is not even a built-in symbol. OP probably meant to use `ClearAll`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. Yeah, I automatically read it as `ClearAll`.

Answer (score 2):

```
T[t_] = ExpToTrig[
   First@DSolve[{θ''[t] + 2*g*θ[t]/(3*(R - ρ)) == 
        0 /. {R -> 1, ρ -> 2, g -> 9.81}, θ[0] == 
       0.52, θ'[0] == 1}, θ[t], t]];
T1[t_] = First@
   NDSolve[{θ''[t] + 2*g*θ[t]/(3*(R - ρ)) == 
       0 /. {R -> 1, ρ -> 2, g -> 9.81}, θ[0] == π/
       6, θ'[0] == 1}, θ, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[{θ[t] /. T[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[{θ[t] /. T1[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: +1 Recommend that you use exact numbers for the parameters and in the first plot set the `WorkingPrecision`. The plot will be much smoother.